# Showing dropdown value in laravel form select List?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Here is my code:

controller file: EmergencyContactsController.php

```
$surnames = DB::table('salutations')->pluck('name'); 
return view('patient/emergencycontacts', ['salutation' => $surnames]);
```

Blade file: patient/emergencycontacts.blade.php

```
    {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'emergencycontacts_store', 'class' => 'form')) !!}
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Salutation') !!}
{{ Form::select('role', ['' => 'Select Role'] + $salutation, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
 </div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('First Name') !!}
{!! Form::text('firstname', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'First Name')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Last Name') !!}
{!! Form::text('lastname', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Last Name')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Relationship') !!}
{{ Form::select('relationship', ['Father', 'Mother', 'Husband','Wife','Son','Daughter','Uncle','Aunty','Other']) }}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Phone') !!}
{!! Form::text('phone', null, array('required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Phone')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::label('Fax') !!}
{!! Form::text('fax', null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Fax')) !!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
{!! Form::submit('Save',array('class'=>'btn btn-primary')) !!}
</div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

When I go to url http://localhost:8000/patient/emergency-contacts/create it gives me error:

> "Unsupported operand types"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change 2 things

In your controller:

```
$surnames = DB::table('salutations')->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
```

So you get an array as `[id => 'value']` and not only `['value']`. In the View:

```
{!! Form::select('role', $salutation, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::select('relationship', ['Father', 'Mother', 'Husband','Wife','Son','Daughter','Uncle','Aunty','Other']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Always 'escape' the Form tags, if not, the HTML will be printed on screen, not parsed.

Answer (score 1):

please use view('patient.emergencycontacts', ['salutation' => $surnames]);